# How to solve MySQL subquery with joins?

Tags: mysql, subquery

Is there a way to retrieve the result from the given tables? Tbh I have no idea how to accomplish this with subqueries. Current examples are full with datetime cases. I find them immensely confusing...

Table #1

```
** red **
|id| green_id |
|--| ---------|
|1 | 1        |
|2 | 2        |
|3 | 3        |
```

Table#2

```
**green**
|id| blue_id | enum |
|--| --------|------|
|1 | 1       |100   |
|2 | 1       |101   |
|3 | 1       |102   |
|4 | 2       |105   |
```

Table#3

```
**blue**
|id| title |
|--| ------|
|1 | abc   |
|2 | def   |
|3 | ghi   |
```

MySQL query

```
SELECT 
    r.*,
    g.enum AS g_enum,        
    ???????? g.enum_max ????????? <--- how
    b.title AS b_title 
  FROM red AS r
  LEFT JOIN green AS g
    r.green_id = g.id
  LEFT JOIN blue AS b
    g.blue_id = b.id
  WHERE 
    r.id = 1
```

Where **g.enum_max** would be:

```
SELECT MAX(enum) FROM green WHERE blue_id = 1
```

*Result where r.id=1*

```
|id| green_id | g_enum | g_enum_max | blue_title |
|--| ---------|--------|------------|------------|
|1 | 1        | 100    | 102????    | abc        |
```

Comment: Well, It's easily rectified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subqUery for thaT

```
SELECT 
    r.*,
    g.enum AS g_enum,        
    (SELECT MAX(enum) FROM green WHERE blue_id = g.blue_id) g_enum_max ,

    b.title AS b_title 
  FROM red AS r
  LEFT JOIN green AS g ON
    r.green_id = g.id
  LEFT JOIN blue AS b ON
    g.blue_id = b.id
  WHERE 
    r.id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for you time and solution. It totally slipped my mind that I can make subq in this place. Much appreciated!